# How to move from community edition to professional edition in dnn?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I had made a website that is hosted on server. it is in dnn community edition and i want to move it to professional edition. I purchased the licence key but i don't knw how to move it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the Professional Upgrade package.
You just overwrite your current Community web folders with the upgrade package.
Hit the site with a browser and enter www.domainname.com/install/install.aspx?mode=upgrade

You may also need to run this URL: www.domainname.com/install/install.aspx?mode=installresources

Make sure you put the correct DOMAIN URL at the front!!!

Once you have upgrade click "Go to your Site" at the bottom of the installation page
Log in 
Under Host --> Professional Services you will see "Activate Your License".
Go to that module and you enter your License key and email address and activate your Professional Edition.

You paid for Professional Edition which entitles you to paid support. 
If anything above is unclear please contact DotNetNuke Support, you should have contact information, email and phone #, in an email from when you purchased your Professional License.

HTH,
Ken Grierson
QA Lead